# flask gunicorn deployment failed

Tags: flask, gunicorn, back4app

I am trying to run my app on back4app and has the following issue:

2023-05-07T11:39:43.342Z
SYSTEM
LAUNCHING CONTAINER...

2023-05-07T11:39:46.143Z
SYSTEM
CHECKING HEALTH...

2023-05-07T11:39:46.144Z
SYSTEM
trying to hit the 8080 port using http

2023-05-07T11:39:46.151Z
SYSTEM
it looks that no process is listening to the 8080 port using http

2023-05-07T11:39:46.153Z
SYSTEM
trying again in 1s

2023-05-07T11:39:47.154Z
SYSTEM
trying to hit the 8080 port using http

2023-05-07T11:39:47.157Z
SYSTEM
it looks that no process is listening to the 8080 port using http

2023-05-07T11:39:47.159Z
SYSTEM
trying again in 2s

2023-05-07T11:39:49.159Z
SYSTEM
trying to hit the 8080 port using http

2023-05-07T11:39:52.162Z
SYSTEM
http request to the 8080 port timed out after 3s

2023-05-07T11:39:52.166Z
SYSTEM
The container exited before becoming healthy. Please check the container logs.

2023-05-07T11:39:52.167Z
SYSTEM
deployment failed

My dockerfile :

> FROM python:3.9-slim
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
>
> COPY . .
>
> EXPOSE 8080
>
> CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "app:app"]

Flask run:

> if **name** == "**main**":
> app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

Requirements.txt:

> Flask==2.3.2
> Jinja2==3.1.2
> MarkupSafe==2.1.2
> Werkzeug==2.3.3
> blinker==1.6.2
> click==8.1.3
> colorama==0.4.6
> itsdangerous==2.1.2
> Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
> dominate==2.7.0
> visitor==0.1.3
> Flask-CKEditor==0.4.6
> Flask-Gravatar==0.5.0
> Flask-Login==0.6.2
> Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.3
> SQLAlchemy==2.0.12
> greenlet==2.0.2
> typing-extensions==4.5.0
> Flask-WTF==1.1.1
> idna==3.4
> charset-normalizer==3.1.0
> certifi==2023.5.7
> itsdangerous==2.1.2
> MarkupSafe==2.1.2
> requests==2.30.0
> urllib3==2.0.2
> WTForms==3.0.1
> gunicorn==20.1.0

Container log:

> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.837Ze1abceaa[2023-05-07 11:39:46 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.838Ze1abceaa[2023-05-07 11:39:46 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Using worker: sync
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.838Ze1abceaa[2023-05-07 11:39:46 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.843Ze1abceaa[2023-05-07 11:39:46 +0000] [7] [INFO]
> Booting worker with pid: 7
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa[2023-05-07 11:39:46 +0000] [7] [INFO]
> Worker exiting (pid: 7)
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaaModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'app'
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File "",
> line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File "",
> line 1007, in _find_and_load
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File "",
> line 1030, in _gcd_import
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa return
> _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in
> import_module
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa mod = importlib.import_module(module)
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359,
> in import_app
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line
> 48, in load_wsgiapp
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa return self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line
> 58, in load
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa self.callable = self.load()
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line
> 67, in wsgi
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 146, in load_wsgi
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa self.load_wsgi()
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 134, in init_process
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa worker.init_process()
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line
> 589, in spawn_worker
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaaTraceback (most recent call last):
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:46.846Ze1abceaa[2023-05-07 11:39:46 +0000] [7]
> [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:47.028Ze1abceaa[2023-05-07 11:39:47 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Shutting down: Master
>
> 2023-05-07T11:39:47.028Ze1abceaa[2023-05-07 11:39:47 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Reason: Worker failed to boot.
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.458Z8788bd13[2023-05-07 13:21:26 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.460Z8788bd13[2023-05-07 13:21:26 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Using worker: sync
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.460Z8788bd13[2023-05-07 13:21:26 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.528Z8788bd13[2023-05-07 13:21:26 +0000] [7] [INFO]
> Booting worker with pid: 7
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13[2023-05-07 13:21:26 +0000] [7] [INFO]
> Worker exiting (pid: 7)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'app'
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File "",
> line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File "",
> line 1007, in _find_and_load
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File "",
> line 1030, in _gcd_import
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 return
> _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in
> import_module
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 mod = importlib.import_module(module)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359,
> in import_app
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line
> 48, in load_wsgiapp
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 return self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line
> 58, in load
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 self.callable = self.load()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line
> 67, in wsgi
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 146, in load_wsgi
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 self.load_wsgi()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 134, in init_process
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 worker.init_process()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13 File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line
> 589, in spawn_worker
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.532Z8788bd13[2023-05-07 13:21:26 +0000] [7]
> [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.639Z8788bd13[2023-05-07 13:21:26 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Reason: Worker failed to boot.
>
> 2023-05-07T13:21:26.639Z8788bd13[2023-05-07 13:21:26 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Shutting down: Master
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.244Zaa33b43a[2023-05-07 13:33:10 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.246Zaa33b43a[2023-05-07 13:33:10 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.246Zaa33b43a[2023-05-07 13:33:10 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Using worker: sync
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.251Zaa33b43a[2023-05-07 13:33:10 +0000] [7] [INFO]
> Booting worker with pid: 7
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a[2023-05-07 13:33:10 +0000] [7]
> [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43aTraceback (most recent call last):
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line
> 589, in spawn_worker
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a worker.init_process()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 134, in init_process
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a self.load_wsgi()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 146, in load_wsgi
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line
> 67, in wsgi
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a self.callable = self.load()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line
> 58, in load
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a return self.load_wsgiapp()
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line
> 48, in load_wsgiapp
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359,
> in import_app
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a mod = importlib.import_module(module)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in
> import_module
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a return
> _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File "",
> line 1030, in _gcd_import
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File "",
> line 1007, in _find_and_load
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43a File "",
> line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.254Zaa33b43aModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'app'
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.255Zaa33b43a[2023-05-07 13:33:10 +0000] [7] [INFO]
> Worker exiting (pid: 7)
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.427Zaa33b43a[2023-05-07 13:33:10 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Shutting down: Master
>
> 2023-05-07T13:33:10.431Zaa33b43a[2023-05-07 13:33:10 +0000] [1] [INFO]
> Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Corrected work directory id Dockerfile:

> FROM python:3.9-slim
>
> WORKDIR /main
>
> COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt RUN pip install --upgrade pip
> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
>
> COPY . .
>
> EXPOSE 8080
>
> CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "main:app"]

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an other application running on the server or else you can use other port .

Comment: They suggest this port in the documentation https://www.back4app.com/docs-containers/run-a-flask-container-app